# Infinite Scroll in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

i was trying infinite scroll  in ionic according to this https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/.

every thing works fine i am able to get the number and loader to be displayed.

When i try to implement an array of strings i am getting errors

here is my code

```
<ion-content>

 <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</ion-item>
 </ion-list>

 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

my .ts file

```
    items = ['apple', 'orange', '1','apple',.......];

    doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.items.push( this.items.length );
      }

      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

> here is the error i am facing

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. 

 L35:  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  L36:    this.items.push( this.items.length );
```

Comment: In the example the `items` array contains indices..so each time a new number is added with `this.items.length`. You have an array of strings. You will have to add based on your requirements

Comment: can you provide me a plunkr  or a demo  for dynamic array

Comment: @suraj i have  tried to change it but not able to get that

Comment: you have ten strings in items?

Comment: i am not saying only 10 i may have many the above array of items is just dummy one but for demo purpose i have used strings of array and trying to show infinete scroll @suraj

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `this.items.length` to a string array.

```
items = ['apple', 'orange', '1','apple',.......];
items2=['dfv',...];//ten additional items for demo. the additional items can come from anywhere else eg. an http request.

    doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.items.push( this.items2[i] );
      }

      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: i too created an separate empty array and changed . after the http.get request and assign the value to items array that you have and then i have items2 array as empty and  in my settimeout funtion  i used this.items2.push(this.items[i]) but i am not able to getting the loader after my 10 strings

Comment: you might want to create a question with the actual code. Not sure what could be wrong from the description you are giving

Comment: i have tried many times i am getting only the first 10 items of the array show again and again please check  the answer again

Comment: you want to add one element for each scroll action?

Comment: for back end i got all the data so when i invoke the back end again i am not able to get any new product how to stop the infinte scroll now

Comment: can you create a question with your problem.. cant tell without any code

Comment: give me some time i will remove the unwanted code and provide you only required code because i have more code in this part